# Rails testing template render error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

In the course I have been doing,I was given a homework assignment to make an integration test of the users' signup page.Here is my work:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "create a new user" do
    get '/signup'
    assert_template '/signup'
    assert_difference 'User.count',1 do
      post :create,user:{username: "jay",email:"jay_lann@gmail.com",password: "american"}
      assert_redirected_to user_path(assigns(:user))
    end
    assert_template "users/#{:user.id}"
  end
end
```

However,an error pops out when I `rake test` the file.It throws out this error:

```
Failure:
SignupTest#test_create_a_new_user [c:/Users/dadi/Desktop/project1/app/test/integration/signup_test.rb:7]:
expecting <"/signup"> but rendering with <["shared/_errors", "users/_form", "users/new", "layouts/_navigation", "layouts/_messages", "layouts/_footer", "layouts/application"]>
```

I've seen some solutions for this error,but none of them have worked.Help is greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance!

(Since I am not well-versed yet in testing,pointing out any error I have made but hasn't popped out yet would mean much to me.)

EDIT:I have tried your solutions.My code looks like this now:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "create a new user" do
    get '/signup'

    assert_difference 'User.count',1 do
      post :create,user:{username:"jay",email:"jay_lann@gmail.com",password: "american"}
      assert_redirected_to user_path(assigns(:user))
    end
    assert_template "users/#{:user.id}"
  end
end
```

However,I receive this error when I `rake test` the file:

```
Error:
SignupTest#test_create_a_new_user:
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.example.com:80create
    test/integration/signup_test.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <class:SignupTest>
'
    test/integration/signup_test.rb:8:in `block in <class:SignupTest>'
```

The error is in lines 8 and 9,but I can't figure out what's wrong(invalid URI code,I know,but I can't figure out where did I make an URI error).

Comment: Do you have a password confirmation on that page, or any other required fields? You are having some kind of error when submitting the form.

Comment: `assert_template '/signup'` is the wrong code. Here you should assert what template is rendered. Change it to `assert_template "users/new"`

Comment: You cannot both redirect and render template. I think if this is the success path, you just need to assert that  the user is redirected.